# Angular 1.X creating a form with value that is incremented/decreased by button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular to provide users with a form for which they can enter values, but want to provide +/- buttons to allow them to use it if desired (tablets etc)

My knowledge of angular is still being expanded and am unsure how to complete the task, I've currently setup validation but not sure how to tackle this one. Should I put a default value into the input, e.g. 0 and called {{count}} that is increased and decreased? or try to affect the ng-model directly.

Here it is currently, also nothing happens when the buttons are pressed.

Basically the form collects information, which is then sent to the calculator service which runs some numbers.

HTML

```
<div class="form-block">
                    <label for="totalStaff">Number of Staff</label>
                    <button ng-click="staff.staffTotal--">-</button>
                    <input class="form-control max-width" type="number" id="totalStaff" name="totalStaff" placeholder="Total Staff" 
                        ng-model="staff.staffTotal" 
                        ng-blur="myform.totalStaff.$touched=true" 
                        ng-required="true" 
                        placeholder="{{myform.totalStaff.$touched && myform.totalStaff.$error.required ? 'Please Enter a value' : 'Induction Courses'}}" ng-class="{'input-error': myform.totalStaff.$touched && myform.totalStaff.$error.required}" />
                    <button ng-click="staff.staffTotal++">+</button>
                </div>
```

Controller

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("app");

    app.controller('StaffDetailCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "CalculatorService", function($scope, $location, calculatorService) {
        $scope.clicked = function() {
            calculatorService.setStaff($scope.staff);
            $location.path('/additionalfeatures');
        };

        $scope.staff = angular.copy(calculatorService.getStaff());
    }]);
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Here is a plunker for you with` [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gUSTJuTpsf78RAAo23Ee?p=preview).

The best way to share data across your app is factories. Also please read about [watchers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, I just needed the syntax for the staff = staff + 1, I already use a factory but didn't include it in the code, thanks for the good demo!